# Get JSON response var outside of jQuery function?

Tags: jquery, json, variables, var

I have the following jQuery function:

```
function deleteHype(){
    FB.api('/me/launchhype:hype', function(response) {
            $.each(response.data, function(i, obj){
                    if (obj.data.launch.url == '<?php the_permalink(); ?>') {
                            var delete_launch_id = parentObj=obj.id;
                    }
            });
    });
}
alert(delete_launch_id);
```

Lets say in the IF statement the var "delete_launch_id" is "X". Well if I try to do the alert "delete_launch_id" outside the function it is "undefined". I want it to give me back "X" (the hypothetically value that was set).

How can I do this? I'm lost and can't seem to find a similar example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By popular demand, here's a more in depth look at why the variable "delete_launch_id" isn't available at the point where it's accessed by the "alert" function.

There's a couple things going on.

First, the FB.api function is most likely an asynchronous AJAX call. JavaScript isn't truly asynchronous (yet), but in this case, it effectively behaves so. What that means is that when asynchronous code executes, code after it will continue executing while the async code waits for a response. So, there's a good chance that if you call "deleteHype", and then "alert" immediately following it, FB.api response won't have returned by the time "alert" is called. And as such, anything set within that async code won't be available yet.

The second issue is that JavaScript has "functional scope." What that means, in practice, is that a variable defined inside a function is only available inside that function. It only has "scope" within that function. Consider the following code:

```
var foo = 1;
if(1 === 1) {
    // non-function block. foo is accessible in here, and any changes to foo will be seen outside this block.
    foo = 2;
}
// foo is 2

function change() {
    // functional scope. variables defined in here are only available here
    foo = 3;
    var bar = 1;
}

// foo is 2 because we haven't called change yet
// bar is "undefined"

change();

// foo is 3
// bar is "undefined"
```

"foo" changed because it had scope outside the function, so the function can access it.
"bar" however, only has scope inside that function and doesn't exist anywhere else.

In the original example, "delete_launch_id" is declared inside several functions, actually, so it is not available anywhere else.

My first answer addresses these issues by passing a function into the "deleteType" function as a "callback" that will be called only when the async code is finished and returns. That handles issue #1. The callback function then has "delete_launch_id" passed to it, which makes it available. The format I gave may seem a little weird:

```
deleteHype(function(delete_launch_id) {
    // alert
});
```

What's going on here is that we're actually passing a function as a variable. It's an "anonymous" function (no name). So deleteType treats is like a variable (because it is), and can call it, because it's a function, and the code inside it will execute when it's called. It's a really handy pattern.

I hope that helps a bit. This is confusing stuff at first.

Comment: You rock. Thanks so much for this explanation. Makes a lot more sense.

Answer (score 0):

Declare the variable as a global (or in a namespace accessible wherever you need it).

The problem is that once you do that, you need to worry about when it is accessed, and whether or not it is reasonable to access it at that time. Better solutions depend on what you're actually trying to do.

In general, however, it's best to keep that kind of asynch stuff local, and use functions to manipulate state within the callback. For example, you could pass a function to `deleteHype` that did the "right" thing with the ID, do the work within the callback, manipulate the DOM from either the callback or a function passed to it, etc.

Comment: Personally, I would never encourage a beginner to actually put a variable in global scope. It's a bad habit you don't want to get into.

Comment: @reedlauber Which is why there's more than the first sentence. It is, however, an actual way to accomplish what they want (modulo the rest of my answer), and isn't always the horror people make it out to be. It's a tool, like anything else--it can be abused, but isn't always unequivocally "wrong". Also, there is a limit to what a beginner knows, and can do and still be able to debug it.

Comment: You can't declare a global variable, modify the variable inside a function and then pass that variable to another function without passing the variable as a parameter.

Comment: @Ohgodwhy Not really sure what you said, or how it relates to the answer or comments. You wouldn't need to pass a global at all--it's global. That's why it's dangerous and ill-advised.

Answer (score 0):

I won't get into all the reasons why you can't "see" delete_launch_id at that point in the code, but maybe something like this would work?:

```
function deleteHype(callback){
    FB.api('/me/launchhype:hype', function(response) {
            $.each(response.data, function(i, obj){
                    if (obj.data.launch.url == '<?php the_permalink(); ?>') {
                            if(typeof callback === 'function') {
                               callback(obj.id);
                            }
                    }
            });
    });
}

deleteHype(function(delete_launch_id) {
    alert(delete_launch_id);
});
```

Comment: I think "getting into" all the reasons why you can't see delete_launch_id from that point in the code is exactly what the OP needs to be able to understand the underlying technology as opposed to being spoonfed the code. Teach a man to fish...

Comment: I agree, but functional scope, closures and async code are pretty big topics. Next time...

Comment: This doesn't seem to do anything? And for the record, I do agree with Paolo, I know this may be confusing to explain but please know I'm not necessarily looking for an easy answer. It helps to understand what is going on, too! :)

Comment: Fair enough. I'll add another answer with some more in depth explanation.

Comment: I would really appreciate that. Both help. An example to see what the correct way is and a slight explanation so I can grasp for later use! :)

Comment: (I did get your code working but again, the explanation would help, if you have the time! :) Thanks!)

Answer (score 0):

What you need to do is pass the variable as a parameter between two functions.

```
function deleteHype(){
  FB.api('/me/launchhype:hype', function(response) {
    $.each(response.data, function(i, obj){
      if (obj.data.launch.url == '<?php the_permalink(); ?>') {
        var delete_launch_id = parentObj=obj.id;
      }
    });
  });
}
function grabID(delete_launch_id){
  alert(delete_launch_id);
}
```

Your first function is completely correct. Now you just need a second function to grab the parameter, and output it; like below.

```
function grabID(delete_launch_id){
  alert(delete_launch_id);
}
```

Now you can use grabId where you need to output the delete_launch_id.

Comment: I'm not sure where I put this new function you gave me? Can you give me an example? Thanks!